# Pandas dataframe modification with .loc does not work as intended

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do what seems to be a simple task:

```
mult=0     
X_test['f'].loc[test_data[benefit_type_feature] != 1]= mult * X_test['f'].loc[test_data[benefit_type_feature] !=1 ]
```

Simply trying multiply those who fit the condition above by a scalar. 
In reality, nothing happens. X_test does not change at all.

X_test / test_data are practically the same DF with diff columns, so no worries.

Also, I tried to print just this part:

```
print(mult*X_test['f'].loc[test_data[benefit_type_feature]!=1])
```

And it seems that it prints what I intend to apply to the left side, it just doesn't apply it.

Obviously, I know a couple other ways to make it work - but I want to understand why this doesn't.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really intend to multiply ```0``` to other values?
Also, please give some more inputs, like a sample dataframe, etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, I tried `p['test'].loc[r['test']%2==0] = 2*p['test'].loc[r['test']%2==0]` where p and r are `pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]); [p/r].columns = ['0', 'test', '2']`. Am I doing something differently?

Comment: Vinu, the mult variable is calculated during the run. For simplification matters, I tried applying zero to it. The data has many columns so a sample of it would be huge, but I'll provide something


Piotr it seems to be similar. Does the application work for you?

Thank you both for trying to help